# How to tell if a React web-component button is disabled in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, web-component

We're in the process of replacing our custom react components with components from the company's design system.
These are web-components and it has been made a react-wrapper to make them work in React.

The element is rendered like this in our app:

```
<custom-button title="" data-test-id="save" disabled mode="primary">
    #shadow-root
        <button data-mode="primary" size="small" type="button" title="" disabled>Save</button>
</custom-button>
```

In Cypress I have tried to check if it is disabled like so:

```
cy.getByTestId('save').should('be.disabled'); //Doesn't work, but its the way I want to do it
cy.getByTestId('save').find('button').should('be.disabled'); // Works
```

The first way doesn't work but its the way i want to do it because thats how all our tests work today.
I want to having having to do the second way because that means we have to handle buttons from our design-system different from regular buttons.

Does anyone know why the first way doesnt work? Even though the `<custom-button>` has the `disabled` attribute applied to it in the DOM?

Comment: ``getByTextId`` selects the ``<custom-button>`` element, **not** the ``<button>`` inside its shadowDOM. ``.find('button')`` _dives_ into shadowDOM and returns the ``<button>``. The ``disabled`` attribute only exists on ``<button>`` and a few other elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Comment: You can give a `data-test-id` directly to the button itself not its parent.

Comment: or use a more elaborate selector have a look at https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between `attribute` and `property`.

Under the hood `cy.getByTestId('save').should('be.disabled')` is checking that the element has **property** `disabled`. The standard button translates the **attribute** `disabled` into a corresponding property, so it passes the above assertion.

The custom button obviously does not have that behavior, so it might be difficult to treat `custom-button` the same as `button`.

---

One thing that works for your sample is

```js
cy.getByTestId('save').should('have.attr', 'disabled')
```

This should work for all occurrences of `custom-button` (if my assumption about it's behavior is correct).

If you have trouble with standard `button`, you can check both:

```js
cy.getByTestId('save').should($el => {
  return $el.attr('disabled').length > 0 || $el.prop('disabled').length > 0
})
```

You can make a custom assertion if that's a pain to code everywhere.

---

IMO using `.find('button')` isn't optimal, since it's an internal implementation of the `custom-button`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments state, you only retrieve the `custom-button` element and not the `button`, which has the `disabled` attr.

The working solution is fine.

```js
cy.getByTestId('save').find('button').should('be.disabled')
cy.getByTestId('save').contains(/save/i).should('be.disabled') // find based on text instead
```

You can check if in your design-system repo if a data-testid can be passed to the component or add the change yourself, which could be a more cumbersome process.